# Query for finding Persons with most points

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using Mysql and have these tables: (only important columns shown)

Person
**id**, primary key

Post
**id**, primary key
**points**, INT

Visit
**id**, primary key
**person_id**, refers to Person
**post_id**, refers to Post

What I want to find is the Persons (top 5) with most points overall? And the persons with most points on each Post.

Can anyone please guide me? Any help is deeply apreciated!

Comment: How do you wish to handle ties?  As in, what if you have two people tied for 5th place (or 1st for that matter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top 5 persons with most points overall:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    SUM(Post.points) AS total_points
FROM
    Person p
    INNER JOIN Visit v
        ON p.id = v.person_id
    INNER JOIN Post
        ON v.post_id = Post.id
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    SUM(Post.points) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Top 5 persons with most points in one post:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    MAX(Post.points) AS best_post_points
FROM
    Person p
    INNER JOIN Visit v
        ON p.id = v.person_id
    INNER JOIN Post
        ON v.post_id = Post.id
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    MAX(Post.points) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Top 5 posts:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    Post.points
FROM
    Person p
    INNER JOIN Visit v
        ON p.id = v.person_id
    INNER JOIN Post
        ON v.post_id = Post.id
ORDER BY
    Post.points DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

For each Post

`SELECT id FROM Person where id in (SELECT person_id FROM Visit where post_id in 
(SELECT id FROM Post order by points DESC limit 5))`

Overall (not sure if will work, not tested)

`SELECT id FROM Person where id in (SELECT distinct(person_id) FROM Visit where post_id in 
(SELECT id FROM Post order by points DESC limit 5) GROUP BY person_id )`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT P.id , SUM(PP.points)
 FROM PERSON P JOIN VISIT V ON ( V.person_id = P.id ) 
 JOIN POST PP JOIN ON ( PP.id = V.post_id )
 GROUP BY P.id
 ORDER BY PP.points DESC
)
LIMIT 5;

SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT P.id , COUNT(*) NUM_OF_POST
   FROM PERSON P JOIN VISIT V ON ( V.person_id = P.id ) 
   JOIN POST PP JOIN ON ( PP.id = V.post_id )
   GROUP BY P.id
   ORDER BY NUM_OF_POST DESC
)
LIMIT 5;
```